# Would like to split columns with a variable and not have to use cases

Tags: excel, vba

Would like to handle the cases with variables but I can't figure out how to set how many arrays to build based off number delineators found, thanks for any assistance that can be provided.

```
Sub clarity()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Columns("A:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B14").Select

For x = 1 To 25
If Y > 2 Then Exit For
If Cells(x, 1) = "" Then
Cells(x, 1).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
x = x - 1
Else
Y = Y + 1
End If
Next

'count number of deliminators
For x = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))

If Len(Cells(x, 2)) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(x, 2), ",", "")) > Z Then
Z = Len(Cells(x, 2)) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(x, 2), ",", ""))
End If
Next


For Y = 1 To Z
Range("C:C").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next Y


Columns("B:B").Select
Select Case Z
Case 1
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 2
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 3
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 4
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 5
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 6
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Case 7
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 8
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 9
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 10
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Select

For x = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))


If Cells(1, x) = "ns1:coordinates" Then
pStart = x
pEnd = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))
fEnd = "Cells(1," & x - 1 & ")"
End If
If Cells(1, x) = "ns1:description" Then
fStart = "Cells(1," & x & ")"
End If
Next x



Debug.Print fStart & " First Description "
Debug.Print fEnd & "  Last Description"
Debug.Print pStart & " First Point"
Debug.Print pEnd & " Last Point"


For Header = 0 To Z

If Header = 0 Then Cells(1, 2 + Header) = "Pitch"
If Header = 1 Then Cells(1, 2 + Header) = "SQFT"
If Header > 1 Then Cells(1, 2 + Header) = "Flashing " & Header - 1

Next



'Find Column
For col = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))
If Cells(1, col) = "ns1:coordinates" Then Exit For
Next
Debug.Print col

' Counts Dilinetors
For x = 1 To 99
If Len(Cells(x, col)) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(x, col), ",", "")) + Len(Cells(x, col)) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(x, col), " ", "")) > Z Then
Z = Len(Cells(x, col)) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(x, col), ",", "")) + Len(Cells(x, col)) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(x, col), " ", ""))
End If
Next

Columns(col).Select

Select Case Z



Case 3
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 4
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 5
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 6
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 7
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 8
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 9
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 10
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 11
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 12
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 13
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 14
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 15
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 16
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 17
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 18
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 19
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 20
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 21
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 22
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 23
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 24
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 25
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 26
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Case 27
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:coordinates]]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Select


For x = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))
If Cells(1, x) = "ns1:coordinates" Then Exit For
Next
Debug.Print x
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))

pCount = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1")) - x) / 3, 0)

' Label points
Cells(1, x) = "X1"
Cells(1, x + 1) = "Y1"
Cells(1, x + 2) = "Z1"

For Y = 1 To pCount - 1
Cells(1, x + (Y * 3)) = "X" & Y + 1
Cells(1, x + 1 + (Y * 3)) = "Y" & Y + 1
Cells(1, x + 2 + (Y * 3)) = "Z" & Y + 1
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Would like to handle the cases with variables but I cant figure out how to set how many arrays to build based off how many delineators found, thanks for any assistance that can be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of code there but just to address your specific question, you can use a function to generate your fields array:

```vb
Function FieldsArray(numFields As Long)
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    ReDim arr(0 To numFields - 1)
    For i = 0 To numFields - 1
        arr(i) = Array(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
    FieldsArray = arr
End Function
```

You could call this like:

```vb
    Columns("B:B").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ns1:description]]"), _
                  DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True, _
                  FieldInfo:=FieldsArray(Z + 1), _
                  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Worth noting that your delimiter-counting code may fail when you have quoted fields which include one or more commas.

Comment: The spreadsheet this is sorting will never have quoted strings in the targeted cells, so there  shouldn't be any missed delimiters for the intended use. Will def keep that in mind for any future projects, thanks!